# Есть ли в tkinter (canvas) метод if touch или что-то типо того

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, if, touch

Я разрабатываю игру на tkinter и мне нужно чтобы если игрок (или любой другой объект) дотрагивался до определенного объекта, что-то прлисходило.
это типо if touch в scratch. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Почему вы не используете для этого более удобный PyGame?
Вообще есть метод tag_bind(). мне кажется, он вам наиболее подходит. используя его, вы сможете через условный оператор прописать все что хотите.